# How to copy one table into another with some additional Data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

I want to copy columns from **table1** into **table2** with some additonal columns in **table2**.

> Although I know the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

But how can I add an additional column's data into table2?

> I've tried this approach but it gives syntax error:

```
// first storing the desired data from table1 into a temporary table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table 
select column1, column2, column3 from table1 
where condition;

// then placing the selected columns into table2
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3,col4) values (
SELECT column1 FROM temp_table, 
SELECT column2 FROM temp_table, 
SELECT column3 FROM temp_table, 
'Additional Value'
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a litteral string (or any other expression) to the column list. Consider:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3,col4)
SELECT
    column1,
    column2,
    column3,
    'Additional Value'
FROM table1
```

Comment: It need not be a 'literal string'. In steead of `'Additional value'`, you can also put a number i.e.: `42`, or a calculation `2*3*7`.

Comment: @Luuk: sure. I edited my answer to be more precise about this.

Answer (score 1):

> Please, follow below query and you can use alias as extra column it's
>   static or expression field:
>   ([SQL-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca41e90c7ae0f368f7f8969277aaec58))

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
 SELECT column1, column2, column3, 'Additional Value' as column4
 FROM table1
 WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it works too, but no need for setting alias in this scenario